# Pycharm Django Debugging is really slow

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a moderate size website but it takes about 30 seconds for PyCharm to start Runserver and be ready to run the app. If I "Run" the app instead of "Debugging" it will only take about 3 seconds to start.

What are some of the things I can do speed up the code change and debugging cycle.
I am using a decent MBP with 16Gb of RAM. So hardware is not the issue.

I have excluded /media files from the project. 
I don't any other large number of files that will cause indexing problems
I am using both Postgres and Mongo db.
I am running Django 1.7 + a dozen of packages like:

```
dj-static==0.0.6
django-annoying==0.8.1
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-bootstrap-form==3.2
django-bootstrap-pagination==1.5.1
django-compressor==1.5
django-extensions==1.5.5
django-filter==0.10.0                              
django-guardian==1.2.5
django-storages-redux==1.2.3
django-widget-tweaks==1.3
djangorestframework==3.1.2                        
django-jinja==1.4.1
```

This is debug output:

```
/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/env-test/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm 4.5 EAP.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --save-signatures --client 127.0.0.1 --port 64097 --file /Users/user1/gitroot/website1/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --verbosity 2
Connected to pydev debugger (build 141.1245)
pydev debugger: process 63926 is connecting

pydev debugger: process 63954 is connecting

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
June 03, 2015 - 09:08:52
Django version 1.7.7, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

**UPDATE:**
Since this post Pycharm has the ability to use Cython as the interpreter. I think that has improved things somewhat. I also moved to use Runserverplus which I think runs faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the debugger is just slow and there is not much you can do about it. Just don't use the debugger unless you absolutely need it (i.e. you are troubleshooting a particularly elusive bug).

I can think of only one thing that may speed up the PyCharm's debugger and that is to turn off the "Collect run-time types information for code insight" setting (located under File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger).

Comment: it's really a pain that there is no solution. there are also some tickets in jetbrain's issue tracking: [PY-10031](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10031#u=1401303786357), [PY-10427](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10427#tab=Comments) but no further hints

Comment: Downvote because encouraging people NOT to use a debugger is harmful to productivity and their success. If you can't debug easily, something should change.

Comment: @pfrank but why do you blame _me_ for the current situation? I don’t work at JetBrains

Comment: The debugger isn't generally slow, for a new project you can connect very quickly to the process and use the debugger. If there are delays, it should be an anomaly that someone should look into, the the norm.

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue improved when I remembered I had ***enabled the debugger to collect type information***.

- Hit `Ctrl-Shift-A` or search under `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger` for `collect run-time types information for code insight`
- Un-check the box and hit `apply`
- See if this helps

I run `PyCharm Community 5.0.1`

Comment: Wow, disabling this slashed my wait time from 30 seconds > 0.3 seconds! This PyCharm feature should come with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the original poster's debug output doesn't include the message about cython.  I came to this post because I couldn't figure out why my pycharm debug was so slow, but later I realized a suggestion for speeding up the debugger  is right here in my debug output.

```
"<some-path-to-python>/python" "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace
```

I hope folks have tried that.  I guess this answer is for the non-output readers of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Need to experiment on these, taken from [Jetbrain blog](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205809209-django-debugger-slow):

> 1. delete all breakpoints
> 2. turn off tracing exceptions
> 3. no runtime type insights

But also look at disabling Django model checking etc to speed up.

I'v used a patch to speed up test cases, 10x faster to run.
So, if you do TDD, functions are less heavier than views. It let you resolve bug quickly.