# Loading data from disk is too slow when debugging Python

Tags: python, performance, debugging

My python program loads a txt file with the size of approximately 300MB line by line and converts each line into float.

```
with open(file) as fp:
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        data.append(float(line))
```

The speed of loading is just okay and takes 10 seconds when I run the code in PyCharm. However, when I debug the same code with PyCharm, it becomes very slow and tasks 2 minutes to load the same data.

Why debugging makes it so slow and is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm Django Debugging is really slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625587/pycharm-django-debugging-is-really-slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging is intrusive, no matter the language. It needs to be intrusive to track what is going on. Assuming this is a Python byte code debugger, you might be able to optimize this particular case just by moving all the work to the C layer so it's not doing any work:

```
with open(file) as fp:
    data = list(map(float, fp))
```

Otherwise, you'll have to look up the debugger docs; most of them have the option to operate in less intrusive modes temporarily to alleviate these sorts of problems. *Edit:* Apparently, [the setting is "Collect run-time types information for code insight"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30626126/364696).

Answer (score 0):

A cursory search of this site reveals this question has been posed at least 3 times already. One indicates ironpython may be the culprit. Another indicates django. As basic as your code appears, I suspect you're using neither, and so would refer you to the third, from Vasily Alexeev, who asserts that the PyCharm debugger is simply just slow, and recommends the following:

I can think of only one thing that may speed up the PyCharm's debugger and that is to turn off the "Collect run-time types information for code insight" setting (located under File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger).